# How can I use progressbar in Android

Tags: android, progress, rssi

I am designing an android app that uses android 4.3 can connect Bluetooth LE 4.0 devices, and I want to know that rssi, so my MainActivity has already get rssi's value,but only numbers, I try to let those number become progress percent, but it's not working?

my get rssi's value function :

```
public void run(){
          int realRssi = rssi+100;
          mDeviceRssi = ressi + "db" ;
          mDeviceRssiView.setText(mDeviceRssi);
}
```

now,here is my question:

```
public class sending_thread extends Thread{
              public void run(){
                      try{
                             while(true){
                                    int progress = Integer.parseInt(mDeviceRSSI);
                                    int[] int_progress = new int[1];
                                    int_progress[0] = progress;
MainActivity.handler.sendMessage(MainActivity.handler.obtainMessage(1,int_progress));
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                              }
                      }
                      catch(Exception e){}
           }
}
```

but int progress = Integer.parseInt(mDeviceRSSI) is not working.

```
private void seekCircle(){
        SeekCircle seekCircle = (SeekCircle) findViewById(R.id.seekCircle);
        try{
             handler = new Handler() {
               public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                   super.handleMessage(msg);
                   switch (msg.what) {
                         case 1:
                          int[] receive_obj = (int[]) msg.obj;
                          updateText(receive_obj[0]);
                          break;
                   }
              }
          };
         }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Handler exception", e.toString());
         }
    send_thread = new sending_thread();
    send_thread.start();
}
```

it's my mistake,the code should be like this:

```
mDeviceRSSI = rssi + " db";
mDeviceRssiView.setText(mDeviceRSSI);

int progress = Integer.parseInt(mDeviceRSSI); //error
int[] int_progress = new int[1];
int_progress[0] = progress;
```

I know mDeviceRSSI is String, but I don't know how to transform String into int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your attribute `mDeviceRssi` contains characters:

```
mDeviceRssi = ressi + "db"
```

and later you do:

```
int progress = Integer.parseInt(mDeviceRSSI);
```

That's not working.

Comment: my mistake,it's should be this: